# JAVASCRIPT object to array conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I search on stackoverflow before post my question, but I didn't find any solution. I have an object like this :

```
"{"COURRIERS":
     {"05. Juridique":
         [{"res_id":100,"type_label":"Plainte","subject":"test23","doctypes_first_level_label":"COURRIERS","doctypes_second_level_label":"05. Juridique","folder_level":2}]
     }
}"
```

And I need to access it like an array, in order to get the information like res_id etc..

How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add a wanted result.

Comment: That is **string**. To convert it to object use `JSON.parse(string)` then use `Object.keys(obj)` to get list of keys which can be used to get the array.

Comment: @Tushar When I display it with console.log I can see it's an object and not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you won't have more than one object/array in each layer, this should get you what you need.

```js
let obj = {
  "COURRIERS": {
    "05. Juridique": [{
      "res_id": 100,
      "type_label": "Plainte",
      "subject": "test23",
      "doctypes_first_level_label": "COURRIERS",
      "doctypes_second_level_label": "05. Juridique",
      "folder_level": 2
    }]
  }
}

let folder = Object.keys(obj)[0]
let type = Object.keys(obj[folder])[0]
let result = obj[folder][type][0]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

(I insert the data inside a variable and print the wanted result with key index)

```js
let obj = {
   "COURRIERS":{
      "05. Juridique":[
         {
            "res_id":100,
            "type_label":"Plainte",
            "subject":"test23",
            "doctypes_first_level_label":"COURRIERS",
            "doctypes_second_level_label":"05. Juridique",
            "folder_level":2
         }
      ]
   }
};

console.log(obj["COURRIERS"]["05. Juridique"][0]["res_id"]);
```

**EDIT**

You want to acess it with variable.
For avoid bug, I strong recommend you to check if the variable value key exist in the array/object like :

```
let folder = 'COURRIERS';

if(folder.indexOf(data) >= 0) { // folder.indexOf(data) = 0
// ... finish the job here :)
}
// indexOf return -1 if the value is not found
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to access it without string, but variable. Like data[folder][type][i]['res_id'] :/

Comment: it's the same, juste replace string with variable `data[folder][type][i]["res_id"]`

Comment: Well, as is, data[folder]... can't work because folder, type etc.. are not index of my object :/

Comment: `let folder = "COURRIERS";`, `let type = "05. Juridique";` and access the object accordingly. Note that `i`is always `0` in this particular case. Access it as `data[folder][type][0]["res_id"]`.

Comment: The thing you didn't understant is that the variable are not the same. Folder could be "COURRIERS" or "TOTO", you know what I mean ? This is why I need to convert it in array to have something like 
array['folder'] = "COURRIERS" or "TOTO" or...
array['type'] = "05. Juridique" or.... 
etc etc...
I don't know if it's clear enought. I have to access the res_id, subject etc attribute but without knowing the label of folder and type

Answer (score 1):

You can gain access to the data in multiple ways. The following below will help clarify some of the way you can access some of the data.

```
myObj.type              = "Dot syntax";
myObj.type              = "Dot syntax";
myObj["date created"]   = "String with space";
myObj[str]              = "String value";
myObj[rand]             = "Random Number";
myObj[obj]              = "Object";
myObj[""]               = "Even an empty string";
```

For your problem you can use the following

```
var x = { 
 "COURRIERS":{
  "05. Juridique":[
     {
        "res_id":100,
        "type_label":"Plainte",
        "subject":"test23",
        "doctypes_first_level_label":"COURRIERS",
        "doctypes_second_level_label":"05. Juridique",
        "folder_level":2
     }
  ]
}};
console.log(x['COURRIERS']['05. Juridique'][0].res_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But as I answered to Mathieu Lescaudron, I have to access it with variable like this : data[folder][type][i]["res_id"]